# when try to run .bat file as background service in windows 10 , given error

Tags: batch-file, service, window, windows-10, background-service

I want to run .bat file as windows service. I used following step , but when try to start service given this error.expect some expert help to resolve this.

1) File location
[image]

2) Create Service command prompt as Admin
[image]

3) Service create , successful and view in Services. 
[image]

4) when try to start given same error
[image]

I try to do it , using this web reference. but it also given same error.

[Ref. [link]](https://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/)

My .Bat file content like this

```
IntelliJIDEALicenseServer_windows_amd64.exe -p 41018 -u a.b
```

when run .bat console every thing working fine.

Comment: seems you forgot a backslash instead of space in front of server.bat in _sc create_ comand, or your batch file contain some missing command or path error

Comment: @elzooilogico can you plz, comment correct one. ?

Comment: I tried this one too , "sc create "IDEA_KEY_1" binpath= "E:\Shared_Folder\SW\Intellij Idea\license-server-from-ishan\server.bat";" but given same error.

Comment: sure, the network drive is connected, when started by task scheduler? Double-check.

Comment: is _e:_ a network drive? have you check if system account has permissions on that drive/folder?

Comment: I have admin right to that folder. it is my "E" drive.not even "C" .so I have admin right.

Comment: you yes, but a service runs under system account unless you set _run under some other user account credentials_ you may set _obj= user password= userpass_ in _sc create_ command so service will run under the given credentials. also, be sure that _e:_ drive is accesible when service starts, or provide the _UNC path_ to exe. see _sc create /?_ for help

Comment: As far as I know the System Account cannot access mapped drive letters. Same goes for Task Scheduler. Put the batch file on a local drive and recreate the service and see if you still get the error.